# Powershell switch statement with Name.Contains

Tags: powershell

I have a series of files that need to be filtered before being added to a job queue. That job queue uses the file type as a parameter of a function. What I'm currently using is this:

```
 foreach ($currentFile in $ListOfTestFiles)
 {
    if ($currentFile.Name.Contains("Test1"))
    {
        $ParameterSet="Type1,$SomeOtherVariable"
    }
    if ($currentFile.Name.Contains("Test2"))
    {
        $ParameterSet="Type2,$SomeOtherVariable"
    }
    if ($currentFile.Name.Contains("Test3"))
    {
        $ParameterSet="Type3,$SomeOtherVariable"
    }
    if ($currentFile.Name.Contains("Test4"))
    {
        $ParameterSet="Type4,$SomeOtherVariable"
    }

    $JobArray += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $func -ArgumentList $ParameterSet
    $JobArray | Receive-Job -Wait   
 }
```

Is there a way to slim this down with a switch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach($currentFile in $listOfTestFiles)
{
    switch -wildcard ($currentFile.Name)
    {
        "*Test1*" {$ParameterSet="Type1,$SomeOtherVariable"}
        "*Test2*" {$ParameterSet="Type2,$SomeOtherVariable"}
        "*Test3*" {$ParameterSet="Type3,$SomeOtherVariable"}
        "*Test4*" {$ParameterSet="Type4,$SomeOtherVariable"}
        default {"Default Behaviour"}
    }
    $JobArray += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $func -ArgumentList $ParameterSet
    $JobArray | Receive-Job -Wait 
}
```

Note that I didn't test this code, but I followed Microsoft example from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
    switch ($currentFile)
{
    {$_.name.contains("Test1")} {$ParameterSet="Type1,$SomeOtherVariable"}
    {$_.name.contains("Test2")} {$ParameterSet="Type2,$SomeOtherVariable"}
    Default {}

}
```